# How can I get a required assembly to deploy to an emulator?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, compact-framework, emulation, windows-ce

I have ported a Windows CE solution from 1.1 to 3.5 (I thought, anyway). I deployed the app from VS 2008  to "USA Windows Mobile 5.0 Pocket PC R2 Emulator", on which "device" my app runs. However, when I attempt to put the app through its paces (exercise its features and functions), I get: "Exception: File or assembly name 'System.Core,Version=3.5.0.0 ..., or one of its dependencies, was not found"

I see that File Explorer has a ".NET CF 2.0" folder, but nothing for ".NET CF 3.5" - yet the app, which has been upgraded to 3.5, was deployed to the device (at least enough so for it to start up)...am I correct in assuming there shuld be such a folder (.NET 3.5)? If not, where should System.Core version 3.5 be located?

Most importantly, how can I get it there, or if it is already there, how can I get it to "come out of hiding"?

### UPDATE

Wishing to follow Gene's suggestion, I selected File > Configure... from the emulator. This is what I see, though (no way to mount the directory as an SD card, AFAICT):

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

### UPDATE 2

Maybe this is masking the real problem; in the Output windows, I see:

*A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException' occurred in System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll*

(many times) and:

*A first chance exception of type 'System.MissingMethodException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll*

Comment: Just for completeness: The `Shared folder` selected in the `General` tab will be mounted as a SD card in the emulator.

Comment: What do I need to do about that? (Is that just an interesting tidbit, or does that mean that there is something else I need to do for it to work?)

Comment: No, just a hint. It's quite useful to exchange files between your computer and the emulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the latest version of the CF installed on the emulator, go to the **Project Properties**, select the **Devices** tab, and just check the box as shown below:

[image: Deploy the latest version]

Whenever it comes time to deploy your application, you will need this CAB file on your device.

The CAB file is located here: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v3.5\WindowsCE`

[image: CAB file path]

Personally, I use `SQL Client` on my devices instead of `SQL CE`. To find the CAB files for it, search the `Program Files (x86)` folder for the one you need. The screenshot below shows `sqlce.wce5.armv4i.CAB`.

[image: search results]

I hope that wasn't too many pictures.

Let me know if you run into any snags.

Comment: Never too many pictures; I'm a "visual" cat; When I tick (those Brits are so cute, I can't help copying their dialect sometime) the "Sign the project output with this certificate" czechbox, the multiline text box stays empty. I reckon I don't have to worry about that (just un"tick" it)? I have had the other czechbox ticked ("Deploy the latest version...") but still get that err msg. By "Whenever it comes time to deploy your application" you mean to the actual handheld device, right (not the virtual device/emulator)?

Comment: Go to the **Signing** tab of your project first, and `tick` the *Sign the assembly* box. It has the option to create a new strong name key file. Once that is done, you should be able to go back to **Devices** and `tick` the *Sign the project output...* box.

Comment: Thanks! If there is ever a welding/coding competition, my dough is definitely on you.

Answer (score 3):

You have two ways:

1. install .Net CF within deloy operation. This can be done be check
   **Deploy the latest version of .Net Compact Framework** in Devices tab in Prject properties.
2. install it manually from CAB file. All
   redistributables can be found in
   **%programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v3.5\WindowsCE**.
   For example: NETCFv35.wm.armv4i.cab

Comment: Note: after installing the CAB, a warm boot is required.

Comment: @Gene: This is to a virtual device/emulator; does it really require a warm boot? If so, how is that done?

Comment: Vasiliy, I already had that tickbox czeched/czechbox ticked. As for option 2, how can I manually install to an emulator?

Comment: First mount the given directory as a SD card (File > Configure), open the file explorer on the emulator, click on the mentioned CAB file and follow the instructions. Then restart the emulator via File > Restart > Warm reset device. Maybe Vasiliy can extend his answer (I won't be at my developer machine until monday).

Comment: @Gene: Thanks, but "all down but nine, pard; set 'em up on the other alley" (I see nothing in File > Configure where I can mount a directory, a horse, or anything else). I'm adding scream shots of what I see with File > Configure to an update to my post.

Comment: No, a warm boot is not required.  Sometime the CAB installer will tell you it is, but it's wrong.

Comment: @Clay: It's right there under General.  The "Shared Folder" text box.  Just give it a path to a folder on your PC and it will mount it as a storage card in the emulator.

Comment: @ctacke: Okay, I was able to navigate to and select:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v3.5\WindowsCE

...but it makes no difference - I still get the same err msg about System.Core being unfound.

Comment: To try to ensure the sandbox was clean of residuals, I shut down and restarted Visual Studio 2008. Now, when I F5, I see, "The current VMID is in use. Wait for the other application to exit." I don't know what a VMID is, but whatever it is, how do I close it?

Comment: So now it doesn't even compile anymore with, "Connection failed because of invalid command-line arguments.  Device Connectivity Component" This is starting to get on my frayed and frazzled nerves; good thing it's Friday.